# Should I report to new colleagues company and if so, how?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

My Colleague has resigned from our company and I’m concerned that her new employer does not know of her actions. She has ‘*ghost called*’ for several years and always had a way to explain her way out.

In the past couple of months, I have managed to get actual proof and submitted it to our HR department. She is unreliable, untruthful and has been spending her last month doing no work while sill getting paid by our company.

I feel it’s fraudulent to not work and still get paid salary and benefits. 
I feel like her behaviour is unaccepatable and it really annoys be to know that she has been getting away for it so long unpunished, only with light warnings.

I almost feel compelled to inform her new employer, but really don’t know how, and I would prefer to remain anonymous. **What do you think is the best thing to do?**
I’m thinking as if I owned the business and was not just an employee.

Comment: Hi OCD, welcome to TWP. Unfortunately, this question, as asked, isn't a good fit for this stack. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a company problem (HR, management) AND your personal feelings towards this person. We can't tell what to do, it's opinion-based, very broad, and any act of denunciation could be illegal (quite apart from the fact that, morally speaking, it's...)

Comment: @OldPadawan - At the moment, yes (and the legal angle is worth mentioning), but I think there can be good answers to questions that may not be ideal. I've had a crack at one below.

Comment: pretty vindictive ambitions, best if you work out your personal issues first, it's not healthy

Comment: What is *‘ghost called’*? Google is finding hits but they don't seem relevant, like abandoned calls due to technical glitches.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that. It's no longer your problem, and no one will thank you for it.

At most, an employer receiving an anonymous note rubbishing one of their new appointments will keep a closer eye on their performance, but a good employer would have been monitoring this without third party intervention, and if the problems still exist will be in the right position to take action. More likely they will disregard it as noise. If the new employer is not a good employer, there's not much anyone can do.

[You specifically mention a company owner rather than an employer, but except in the case of very small companies, monitoring the performance of individual staff is not something an owner is able to do, or should be doing.]

It sounds like your former colleague had become disengaged at your current employer. Sometimes a move to another company is all that's needed to re-engage. Trying to sabotage the possibility of this happening would be petty and would say more about you than about your former colleague.

The best answer to unprofessional behaviour is always professional behaviour. Accept that your former colleague was not a good fit at your current employer (there may have been reasons for this that management know and you don't), and wish them well in their future career.